# Git difftool on current folder?

Tags: git, merge

`git difftool -d wasted..master` works very well but creates temporay folders for each branch even that I am currently on master.

I like to use meld (works with difftool) to actually manually merge some lines in from another branch.

I saw git mergetool, but I am afraid its for automation or works differently then difftool so if its the solution please give me a short overview what it does.